# iMac noise through mixer

Tags: interface, imac

I have an iMac with a Numark interface for audio and MIDI connected with USB. I have the audio out from the computer connected through a patch bay into a Yamaha mixer and speaker system.

My problem is that the computer is very noisy, it's not hum, it is computer noise. For example when the song scrolls in GarageBand or LogicPro I can here noise that coincides with the scrolling. There is also a constant interference. Does anyone know how to get rid of those noises?